# How do I calculate overlap in time between different string variables (in columns) in R?

Tags: r, string, overlap

I would like to make a new column that gives a 0/1 (or FALSE/TRUE) value for each time there is an overlap in time between a question(A/B) and a gaze(away).

Here's a dummy example of the data, where time values are in msec:

```
Begin End Duration Question Gaze  File
1145  1245 100       A            xx_xx_A_xx
1050  1100 50        B            xx_xx_A_xx
1200  1300 100              away  xx_xx_A_xx
1100  1200 100       A            xx_xx_B_xx
1200  1245  45       B            xx_xx_B_xx
1300  1400 100              away  xx_xx_B_xx
```

I'd like to get a new column Q_Gazeoverlap:

```
Begin End Duration Question Gaze  File        Q_Gazeoverlap
1145  1245 100       A            xx_xx_A_xx  
1050  1100 50        B            xx_xx_A_xx
1200  1300 100              away  xx_xx_A_xx   1
1300  1400 100       A            xx_xx_B_xx
1200  1245  45       B            xx_xx_B_xx
1300  1400 100              away  xx_xx_B_xx   0
```

The code I've come up so far is:

```
data$Q_Gazeoverlap <- 0

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){ 
  if(data$Question[i] == "A" | data$Question[i] == "B"){ 
    QuesBegin <- data$Begin[i]
    QuesEnd <- data$End[i] 
    
    for(j in 1:nrow(data)){
      if(data$Gaze[j] == "away"){ 
      GazeBegin <- data$Begin[j]
      GazeEnd <- data$End[j]
    
  
      if (data$File[i] == data$File[j] & data$Question[i] == strsplit(data$File,"_")[[i]][3]){ # check if its the right file, and checks if Question is same as A/B in File by looking at 3rd part of string
          ifelse((GazeBegin < QuesBegin | GazeBegin == QuesBegin) & (GazeEnd < QuesEnd | GazeEnd == QuesEnd) |
           (GazeEnd > QuesEnd | GazeEnd == QuesEnd) |
           (GazeBegin > QuesBegin | GazeBegin == QuesBegin) & (GazeBegin < QuesEnd | GazeBegin == QuesEnd),
         data$Q_Gazeoverlap[j] <- 1, 
         data$Q_Gazeoverlap[j] <- "0" )
      }}}}}
```

But somehow I keep getting "1" values for each of the "away" annotations instead of only for the ones that overlap with A/B depending on the File it's looking at.

Does anyone have any experience with calculating overlap? Much appreciated!

Comment: Split your data into 2: AB rows and away rows, then search for "merge with overlap" solutions.

Comment: Hey Naomi, Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't have the time to give a full answer right now, but for now, have a look into the overlap function in the lubridate package. For any answer, it will be helpful if you convert the two columns "begin" and "end" into just one, which gives a period (begin--end). With the overlap function you can then assess whether periods overlap.
After having done this, as mentioned by zk8754, create two dataframes/tables from the one you have now, one for the questions and one for the gazes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I've split the data into two dataframes, but not sure how to go about the overlap function. Most examples I found use dates or specific times of the day. Am I supposed to get the period by using as.interval? Isn't this the same as using the GazeBegin and Gazend vs. QuestionBegin and GestionEnd variables?

Answer (score 0):

here is a `data.table`-approach..

**sample data used**

```
library( data.table)
DT <- data.table::fread("Begin, End, Duration, Question, Gaze,  File
1145,1245,100,A,,xx_xx_A_xx
1050,1100,50,B,,xx_xx_A_xx
1200,1300,100,,away,xx_xx_A_xx
1100,1200,100,A,,xx_xx_B_xx
1200,1245,45,B,,xx_xx_B_xx
1300,1400,100,,away,xx_xx_B_xx")
```

**code**

This can be done in a (pretty long) `data.table`-oneliner.

Count for each row where `!Gaze == ""` how many rows with `!Question == ""` it overlaps.. If more than zero, return 1, else 0.

```
DT[ !Gaze == "", Q_Gazeoverlap := as.numeric( 
  DT[ !Question == "", ][ DT[ !Gaze == "", ], 
                          on = .(Begin <= End, End >= Begin),
                          .N,
                          by = .EACHI, 
                          allow.cartesian = TRUE ]$N > 0 ) ][]


#    Begin  End Duration Question Gaze       File Q_Gazeoverlap
# 1:  1145 1245      100        A      xx_xx_A_xx            NA
# 2:  1050 1100       50        B      xx_xx_A_xx            NA
# 3:  1200 1300      100          away xx_xx_A_xx             1
# 4:  1100 1200      100        A      xx_xx_B_xx            NA
# 5:  1200 1245       45        B      xx_xx_B_xx            NA
# 6:  1300 1400      100          away xx_xx_B_xx             0
```

if you also want to merge on File, just add the File-field to the `on`-argument, like this:

```
DT[ !Gaze == "", Q_Gazeoverlap := as.numeric( 
      DT[ !Question == "", ][ DT[ !Gaze == "", ], 
                              on = .(Begin <= End, End >= Begin, File),
                              .N,
                              by = .EACHI, 
                              allow.cartesian = TRUE ]$N > 0 ) ]
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried it on the dataset, the same problem occurs: each away is counted as overlapping. Is there any way to adapt it to take into account the file name too? So for file with A count only Question(A), and for file B count only Question(B), and then also only compare overlaps within the same file (only TRUE if in File 1, not 2)?
`Begin End Duration Question Gaze    File       Q_Gazeoverlap`
`1145  1245 100       A                      1_x_A_x`  
`1050  1100 50         A                      2_x_A_x`
`1145  1245 100                     away   2_x_A_x   0`

Comment: Apologies, the example I wanted to present is not showing up very clearly. What I meant is that File can be 01_xx_A_xx, 02_xx_B_xx, 03... etc. So there's a high chance there's an overlap somewhere in the data between Gaze and Question if it's considering all files.

Comment: have you tried adding the `File` in the `on`-argument?

Comment: Do you mean just adding ```on = .(Begin <= End, End >= Begin, File = File)``` ?

Comment: yes, just `on = .(Begin <= End, End >= Begin, File)` will also work

Comment: Thanks again! Adding `File` works, but now it excludes overlaps I'm also interested in such as cases where QuestionBegin <= GazeEnd & QuestionEnd >= GazeEnd. I've tried adapting the conditional in `on` to something equivalent to my initial ifelse statement but the `on` argument seems to be restricted to a max. amount of variables. Would you know of a way around it?

Comment: I was trying something along the lines: 
`((GazeBegin <= QuesBegin) & (GazeEnd <= QuesEnd)) | 
((GazeBegin <= QuesBegin) & (GazeEnd >= QuesEnd)) | 
((GazeBegin >= QuesBegin) & (GazeEnd <= QuesEnd)) | 
((GazeBegin >= QuesBegin) & (GazeEnd >= QuesEnd))`

Comment: then you'll probably be interested in the `data.table::foverlaps()`-function... Lots of examples of the use of this function here on SO. Give it a go, and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: I'm not familiar with data.table(), but seems like foverlaps only works for numeric data. I've tried `Gazedata <- data.frame(data$Begin, data$End, data$Gaze, data$File)
Questiondata <- data.frame(data$Begin, data$End, data$Question, data$File)
require(data.table)
  x = data.table(Gazedata)
  y = data.table(Questiondata)
  setkey(Gazedata)
  setkey(Questiondata)
  foverlaps(Gazedata, Questiondata, by.x = if (!is.null(key(Gazedata))) key(Gazedata) else key(Questiondata),
            by.y = key(Questiondata), type = "any", mult = "all", nomatch = 0L)`
but keep getting an error